# convert long data with mutually non-exclusive categories into wide format

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

```
a1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
                 var=c("A",NA,NA,"B","B","B",NA,NA,NA))

desired_1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),
                      A=c(T,NA,NA),
                      B=c(T,T,NA),
                      None=c(NA,NA,T))

desired_2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3),
                        type=c("A","B","B","None"))
```

what is the most efficient method to generate both `desired_1` and `desired_2` using either `data.table` or `dplyr`?

Comment: Is your `a1` correct?

Comment: I believe you want to get the `desired_2` as the ultimate objective

Comment: @akrun--Yes, can always dcast it into wider form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a group by 'id' with `summarise` to get 'None' `if` all the elements in 'var' is `NA` or `else` return the `unique` non-NA elements of 'var'

```
library(dplyr)
a1 %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   summarise(var = if(all(is.na(var))) "None" else unique(var[!is.na(var)]) )
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   id [3]
#     id var  
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1     1 A    
#2     1 B    
#3     2 B    
#4     3 None
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a1)[, .(var = if(all(is.na(var))) "None" else unique(var[!is.na(var)])), id]
```